# Why is a UINavigationController failing to take ownership of a block callback parameter using ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, exc-bad-access

Given the following code example (iOS 7, Xcode 5):

```
/**
* SampleProvider Class
*/

typedef void(^RequestCallback)(UIViewController *result);

static NSString * const cControllerRequestNotification = @"controllerRequestNotification";
static NSString * const cRequestClassNameKey = @"className";
static NSString * const cRequestCallbackKey = @"callback";

@interface SampleProvider : NSObject
+ (void)requestControllerForClassName:(NSString *)className completion:(RequestCallback)callback;
@end

@interface SampleProvider ()
- (UIViewController *)controllerForClassName:(NSString *)className;
- (void)didReceiveControllerRequest:(NSNotification *)n;
@end

@implementation SampleProvider

#pragma mark - Overrides
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if( self ) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveControllerRequest:) name:cControllerRequestNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Public API

+ (void)requestControllerForClassName:(NSString *)className completion:(RequestCallback)callback{

    NSDictionary *requestInfo = @{ cRequestClassNameKey : className, cRequestCallbackKey : [callback copy] };
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:cControllerRequestNotification object:requestInfo];
}

#pragma mark - Private API

- (UIViewController *)controllerForClassName:(NSString *)className {
    UIViewController *result = nil;
    Class controllerClass = NSClassFromString(className);
    if( (nil != controllerClass) && ([controllerClass isSubclassOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) ) {
        result = [[controllerClass alloc] init];
    }
    return result;
}

- (void)didReceiveControllerRequest:(NSNotification *)n {
    NSDictionary *requestInfo = [n object];
    NSString *className = requestInfo[cRequestClassNameKey];    
    RequestCallback callback = requestInfo[cRequestCallbackKey];

    UIViewController *result = [self controllerForClassName:className];

    if( nil != callback ) {
        callback(result);
    }
}

@end

/**
* SampleViewController Class
*/

@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController
@end
@implementation SampleViewController

#pragma mark - Overrides
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSString *className = @"ClassName";

    [SampleProvider requestControllerForClassName:className completion:^(UIViewController *result) {        
        if( nil != result ) {
            // Result is valid pointer, not a zombie.
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:result animated:YES];
            // Result is released, not nil.
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unable to load controller with class name: %@", className);
        }
    }];
}
@end
```

Why would my UINavigationController fail to take ownership of the callback controller, received by SampleProvider's public class method, even after showing the view?

I'm seeing the following behavior:

- The new controller class is properly allocated and returned via the callback method. Upon entering the callback the result parameter is pointing to valid memory.
- The new controller is pushed to my UINavigationController's navigation stack.
- The newly pushed controller's "viewDidLoad" method is called.
- When inspecting the UINavigationController's "viewControllers" property, the newly pushed controller is referenced in the array.
- The newly push controller is is deallocated while UINavigationController pushViewController:animated: is still executing.
- The new controller is now a zombie.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: It's possible that the actual push is scheduled to run on the main run loop after the stack unwinds... so you'd see a -release first before the push actually happens...

Comment: another option--is your block being run on a thread that isn't the main thread? If yes, then you can surround the `-pushViewController:animated:` with something like `performBlockOnMainThread:` or equivalent

Comment: The block appears to be executing synchronously, however, I attempted to wrap the `-pushViewController:animated:` with GCD using the main queue. That produces the crash before the push occurs. This confuses me because I would expect the GCD block to increment the retain count of the object, preventing its deallocation.

Comment: I updated the sample code to correct unrelated flaws, based on Sean Cier's answer below.

Comment: you can use Instruments to see the call stacks of every retain/release for every object in your app. Maybe you can look at the retain/release trace for the zombie.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a clearcut answer because the answer may be in code you haven't posted -- the code you have posted looks valid apart from two observations (which could lead you to an answer):

- Should that isKindOfClass be isSubclassOfClass? -isKindOfClass: is an
  instance method on NSObject, not a class method.
- Calling pushViewController: synchronously during viewDidLoad seems 
  dangerous. It's quite possible that the state of the view hierarchy
  is not stable at that time. That push should happen in response to
  some other discrete event, I'd think. Try making that push (or the
  entire requestControllerForClassName:) asynchronous via
  dispatch_async, as a test, and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In my implementation, the push happens long after the root controller's view is loaded. But on the plus side, the disadvantages of doing a push in viewDidLoad did not occur to me. Also, you are correct about `isSubclassOfClass`. That one slipped by me when I wrote the sample.